# Parallelism and comma

Tags: parallelism

I have a parallelism question. I want to convey that Kenny wrote a book on Eric Cartman's life. Please see the two versions below and see whether my reasoning next to them makes sense.

1. In 2005, Kenny wrote a book titled "Life and Times of Eric Cartman," which is based on Cartman's life. --> This reads like I am conveying that Kenny wrote a book with this title, and the fact that it is based on Cartman's life is a secondary information.
2. In 2005, Kenny wrote a book based on Cartman's life, titled "Life and Times of Eric Cartman". --> This reads likes the book title is a secondary information. The primary information is that Kenny wrote a book Cartman's life.

thanks,

Comment: I agree with your reasoning.

Comment: Surely the subject of the book is obvious from the title - why do you need to explain it?

Comment: @KateBunting I chose a bad book title for this example.